# Azure Data Factory: does Start Integration Runtime cost me?

Tags: ssis, azure-data-factory

I have several SSIS packages that I want to deploy and to run periodically. I am following [this MS tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-deploy-ssis-packages-azure).

Somewhere near the end there's a command to start Integration runtime. I got a bit put off because it said it will take 20-30mins to complete. So my main question is: Will I get billed if I complete the start Integration runtime command but do not execute any SSIS package?

I read in [Data Factory Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-factory/v2/) that

> An inactive pipeline is charged at $0.40 per month

But I have had no experience with it yet and I want to be certain I am not wasting my dev allowance.

And if it really is (almost) free unless I do start executing packages, once I start the runtime, then am I supposed to just leave it running?

Also, I have searched online several times but didn't find any tutorial on how to create an integration runtime via portal. Is that really the case?

Lastly, I am trying to deploy these SSIS packages to a SQL Server that has nothing to do with either the source or destination SQL Server - both servers are owned by someone else. Is that fine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you will be billed as the SSIS IR is started, regardless if you are executing the package or not. Currently, in ADF V2, Azure SSIS IR is a dedicated pool model, so that as long as your start the pool, it's dedicated for you to use only and it's running. The pricing for the Azure SSIS IR is listed under the section called "SQL Server Integration Services compute resource through Azure-SSIS Integration Runtime" on the ADF V2 pricing page.

if you do not want to be billed while not running packages, you need to stop the IR explicitly. thanks

jimmy

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful. I did test right after and started the IR and left it there overnight and yes I did get billed around $10 the next time I checked. I only executed 1 1-min package in the whole duration IR was started.